# Shopify File after pushing it from local to live store class and section being unset in the live store

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

```html
<div class="page-width {{ section.settings.section_css_class_two }}">

{
"type": "text",
    "id": "section_css_class_two",
    "label": {
      "en": "Section CSS Class"
    },
    "default": {
      "en": "Type your own CSS class"
    }
  },
```

I have added the following code to sections/image-banner.liquid.
File after pushing it from local to live store class and section being unset in the live store.
Can you please explain What is the reason for the class and section being unset in the live store?

I tried the above code and a different way but did not find the solution.

Comment: I think you need to check about the presets into section schema, rather then default.

Comment: Check more [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/architecture/sections/section-schema#presets)